# angularjs directive change ngModel input type number format

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to change the ngModel (`input type="number"`) Format. This code work good in angularjs 1.2.23 version as you see, but in 1.6.4 version not work. any other solution?

```
Output must be: 25,00
```

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.test=25;
})

.directive('price', function($filter) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: '?ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return $filter('number')(value,2);
           });
       }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="test" price>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Input` with type `number` requires `Number` not a `String`.

In your example return value will be a `String`:

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
  return $filter('number')(value,2);
});
```

Use `parseFloat()`. The `parseFloat()` function parses an argument and returns a floating point number. In my approach i have used `step` attribute which increments value for `0.01`.

**JSFiddle:**

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.test=25;
})

.directive('price', function($filter) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: '?ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return parseFloat(value);
           });
       }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" step=".01" price ng-model="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The output when the no decimal must be `25,00` not `25`. step=".01" work when decimal but not when no decimal.

Comment: I know. Maybe someone else can resolve problem. Btw you can resolve it with input type text instead number.